# Get text pf a text node

Tags: jquery, recursion

With `contents()` and recursion I iterate over all elements of an element. If the actual element is a text node I want to get it's text - but `text()` doesn't give anything back.

```
markup += processXml($(this));   

function processXml(element) {
    if (element.nodeType == 3) {
         return $(element).text() // that doesn't work !!
    }
    else {
         var temp = "";
         $(element).contents().each(function() {
            temp += processXml(this);
         });
         return temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead...

```
return element.nodeValue;
```